# Multi label plot in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I want to display multiple plots for some 50 values of H. These plots coincide in a place and I want to know for which values of H it is coinciding. By legend I can differentiate only a limited number of plots with multiple color and markers. But I don't know how to make it for multiple plots.

[image: sample image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can separate curves into 3D-space right by the parameter H:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% prepare line-segments' data into X( {1,nSamples}, {1,2}, {1,H} )
%%                                  Y( {1,nSamples}, {1,2}, {1,H} )
%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

for H = 1:50
   plot3( X(:,1,H), Y(:,1,H),       ...
          X(:,2,H), Y(:,2,H),       ...
          H                         ...
          );                        %% separate curves in Z-direction
end
```